# Apache / Laravel doesn't cache jpg, but other extensions cached

Tags: php, laravel, apache, caching, wamp

I used this code to cache jpg and other image type in my .htaccess file,

Although just files not cached that are in **storage** folder in **laravel**. Also the files in storage has been saved with [uniSharp file manager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/)

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3024000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

All image types have been cached, but jpg doesn't cache

i have also used of this code:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work too

All modules that are need are active in httpd.conf like

```
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
```

And i have also restarted apache server after settings.

I have use of wamp server on windows server 2016

Answer (score 0):

I changed my .htaccess file to this code and now cache work fine:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public "
</FilesMatch>

# BEGIN Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 AddType image/x-icon .ico
 ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript A259200
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
</IfModule>
# END Expire headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|gz)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
     </FilesMatch>
     <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
     </FilesMatch>
     <filesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
     </filesMatch>
     # Disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
     <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
        Header unset Cache-Control
     </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```